# What does RR stand for in RR-manipulator?

Tags: kinematics

I have memorized RR-manipulator as having 2 arms from Google images but "arm" isn't spelled with "R". I also noticed that RRR-manipulator has 3 links. Does R stand for revolute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RR manipulator is commonly used as shorthand for a two revolute joint configuration in a single plane. This provides a reduced configuration space which is helpful for research and education use.

RRR is as you guessed a 3 joint system but usually still remaining in the plane.

I don't believe that there's an official definition for this but it's more of a common shorthand. Other abbreviations you may see are P for prismatic. And sometimes analyses leave the single plane, but use the same or similar shorthand for configuration space. The simplest versions have the plane oriented horizontally, but as you get into dynamic systems turning it vertical will increase the complexity adding weight/gravity.